# Cookie strings come back altered after migrating from Laravel 5.7 to 6.x

Tags: laravel, cookies

I'm migrating an application from Laravel 5.7 to the current LTS release, 6.18.

One side effect I've noticed is that I now get previously existing cookies back in an altered form. For example, under 5.7:

```
$deviceId = $request->cookie('deviceId') // sample value '1234'
```

But under 6.18, when retrieving a cookie set under 5.7:

```
$deviceId = $request->cookie('deviceId') // now same cookie returns 's:4:"1234"'
```

And behavior returns to normal for cookies set and retrieved under 6.18:

```
$deviceId = $request->cookie('deviceId') // once again '1234'
```

Obviously I can write a little helper to translate the unexpected new-style value to the original value, but I was just wondering if I did something wrong in my migration, or there's some other adjustment I was supposed to make to keep this from happening?